# hasNext() function does no terminate while loop

Tags: java

```
public class EOF {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i=1;
        while(sc.hasNextLine()==true)
        {
            String str = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(i+" "+str);
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("completed");
    }
}
```

The last line `System.out.println("completed");` is not executing. The loop does not terminate and is continuously running.

Comment: Type Ctrl-D for unix, Ctrl-Z for windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use this

```
public class EOF {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i=1;
        while(sc.hasNextLine()==true)
        {
            String str = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(i+" "+str);
            i++;
            if(str.equals("stop")){
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("completed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation for Scanner.hasNextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine%28%29):

> This method may block while waiting for input.

That means that if there isn't input waiting to be returned, it will sit and wait for more input to come in.

If your `Scanner` is accepting input from `System.in`, you need to find a better way of deciding when you want to finish input. For instance, if the user types `"quit"`, or if they input a blank line.